# Why does tf.cond appear to run both branches?

Tags: tensorflow

In order to easily switch between training and validation in the same process, I decided to use `tf.cond` in my graph definition.

Consider the following class structure for designing a TF graph :

```
import tensorflow as tf
class OverFeatAccurateBase(object):
    def __init__(self, input, numclasses, trainmode):
        self._numclasses = numclasses
        self._trainmode = trainmode
        self._logits = self._buildmodel(input)

    @property
    def numclasses(self):
        return self._numclasses

    def setmode(self, val):
        self._trainmode = val

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._trainmode

    @property
    def logits(self):
        return self._logits

    def _buildmodel(self, input):
        out = tf.layers.conv2d(input, filters=96,
                               kernel_size=[7, 7],
                               strides=[2, 2],
                               padding='valid',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv1')

        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[3, 3],
                                      strides=[3, 3],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_last',
                                      name='pool1')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=256,
                               kernel_size=[7, 7],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='valid',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv2')

        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[2, 2],
                                      strides=[2, 2],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_last',
                                      name='pool2')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=512,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv3')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=512,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv4')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=1024,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv5')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=1024,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=10 ** (-5)),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv6')

        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[3, 3],
                                      strides=[3, 3],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_last',
                                      name='pool3')

        out = tf.layers.flatten(out, name='flatten')

        out = tf.layers.dense(out, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                  stddev=0.01,
                                  seed=0),
                              bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                  scale=10 ** (-5)),
                              reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                              name='full1'
                              )

        out = tf.cond(tf.equal(self.mode, tf.constant(True)),
                      lambda: tf.layers.dropout(
                          out, seed=0), lambda: tf.Print(out,
                                                         [out],
                                                         'The '
                                                         'shape '
                                                         'is'))

        out = tf.layers.dense(out, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                  stddev=0.01,
                                  seed=0),
                              bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                  scale=10 ** (-5)),
                              reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                              name='full2'
                              )
        out = tf.cond(tf.equal(self.mode, tf.constant(True)),
                      lambda: tf.layers.dropout(
                          out, seed=0), lambda: out)
        logits = tf.layers.dense(out, units=self.numclasses,
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                 kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                     stddev=0.01,
                                     seed=0),
                                 bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                                 kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                     scale=10 ** (-5)),
                                 reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                                 name='output'
                                 )

        return logits
```

Let us now test the above structure with the following snippet

```
from networks.overfeataccuratebase import OverFeatAccurateBase
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inp = np.random.randn(10,221,221,3)


input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 221, 221, 3),
                       name='input')

mode_train = tf.constant(True)

mode_val = tf.constant(False)

net = OverFeatAccurateBase(input, 1000, mode_train)

logits = net.logits

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./tboard', graph=sess.graph)
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={input: inp}))
    net.setmode(mode_val)
    print(sess.run(net.mode))
    print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={input: inp}))
    writer.close()
```

On running the above snippets, it can be seen, despite setting `net.setmode(mode_val)`, it appears that the graph is still running in the training mode, because the `tf.Print` statement in the `tf.cond` node is not executed. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The way that `tf.cond` works is that it runs both branches of the if statement and then it makes sure that the right one is the one that has it's value assigned into the output. That's why you are seeing the print statement show up when you don't expect it to.

It looks like the purpose of your `tf.cond` statements is just to enable or disable dropout. The way I do that in my own code is to make the dropout probability be a placeholder with a default of 1.0. Then during training I feed in the proper dropout probability and during validation/testing I leave the default value and that effectively disables the dropout.

Comment: I have used the placeholder and it works. However, i always worry about its impact on performance. Am I too concerned about the performance aspect ?

Comment: I always assumed that dropout with zero dropout probability was a no-op. Maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: In my case I have used `tf.cond` but instead of using the probability as a placeholder, I just use `tf.cond` based on the value of the placeholder to do or not do the dropout. But as  I said, i want to get some clarity on the use of placeholder with respect to performance. I know it is only a matter of a boolean value, but how would a hardcore performance crazy person would respond ?

Comment: Well tf.cond has a big performance impact because as I said it is executing both branches of the conditional and only using one of them.

Comment: I would actually disagree with that point, because on the running the snippet in the question, I do not see any print statement. I am sure that `tf.cond` does not execute both branches.